# VMWare Player guest does not re-aquire IP on bridged interface after host loses and re-acquires network connectivity

Tags: bridge, vmware-player

I am running a Ubuntu Linux image in VMWare Player on my laptop. The host is Windows XP.

There are two network adapters configured in VMWare Player - one is host-only and the other is bridged. Everything works fine as long as the host does not lose network connectivity.

If the host loses connectivity (even briefly) and then re-acquires it, my bridged adapter in VMWare Player is still unable to get an IP address. The host-only adapter remains unaffected. Disconnecting/Reconnecting the bridged adapter does not help. Simply restarting the guest OS does not help. Restarting VMWare Player does not help. The only remedy is to reboot the host and then bring up VMWare Player all over again.

Is there something I can try to avoid this reboot? I searched the existing questions but they seemed to talk about adapters in NAT mode, whereas I am interested in retaining Bridged mode.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an option there to communicate the host computer's network connectivity state to the guest that you can uncheck. Is VMware tools installed on the guest?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid VMWare tools is not installed. Would you be able to point me to some config file that I should review?

Comment: Install VMware tools.  It is useful in many ways and improves some performance

Comment: I just installed VMWare tools, but still see the same problem after yanking the network cable from the host and plugging it back in.

Comment: Is the host machine a laptop?

Comment: Yes, the host is a laptop; I will update the original description to include this detail.

Comment: Check the device properties and in device manager to see if it is configured to power off the adapter when the cable is unplugged. Try disabling any power management features for the NIC card.

Comment: In Device Manager, I unchecked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" checkbox for the laptop's 'Intel 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection' adapter. Still did not help.

Comment: Does the guest machine replicate the host NIC's state? IE... when you unplug it, does the VM show it as unplugged?

Comment: Sorry about the long delay. Yes, when I unplug the cable from the host, Ubuntu does pop up the brief floating dialog indicating the interface was disconnected. I have never seen that floater come up when the cable is re-connected to the physical port on the host machine.

Comment: You may have to edit a VMX file, perhaps workstation doesn't have the option in the GUI, but what you're after is making sure the guest is not aware of the host's connectivity state.

Comment: Added a picture, since you're getting upstream IP addresses I assume you are using bridged mode, make sure that box is NOT ticked on the guest's networking config?

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that the box was already unchecked..

Comment: If someone else has the ability to experiment with this setting and see whether it works for them, can that person mark this as an accepted answer? Unfortunately, it is not working for me, so I am just resigned to living with the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have spend some lot time on the same problem i have find the solution without need to rebooting or installing vmware tools !

In fact the problem is very vicious because :

- It's appear only with linux guest, never on windows guest.
- you can accumulate it with an other well know problem who appear after copying your VM guest  and know as udev / netrules problem / bab mac address in net rules )but there is any relation between this 2 facts.

This is logical to think that the problem came from your guest VM but **in fact the problem came only from your host.**

On your host you certainly have installed some other nics as “virtualbox host only”, “loopback microsoft” “physical NICS bind to an other network ”, “bleutooth dongle” ...

When you bridge a vm guest directly to the physical network vmware in fact your are connected to the vmnet0 -> workstation assign / fix automatically the NIC to use without as you something and sometime it do not choose the good one ...

VMWARE Workstation never ask you to choose the NIC physical link in order to be connected to the physical network where you got your DHCP (in my case a monowall) and sometime he decided to bind your guest to a logical NIC … without DHCP server, finaly you never get your DHCP lease.

How to solve the problem :

It’s easy you only need to choose and apply the good NIC in **the virtual network editor ** in workstation in order to fix this problem.

Have a nice day !

***Nota: Sorry but i can't post any image I am new on this forum → my reputation is to low …***